# Video autoplay(on) thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I saw on different websites thumbnails for video lightboxes which was like little videos. It was like little autoplaying tiny video thumbnails . This is an example http://www.mariotestino.com/film/latest/. I want to know what it i,s how to search ? is it iframe or video html5 .  Any information please^
Will be happy for any help!<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a video thumbnails, that is animated gif image